# How to split condition columns into factor levels to perform 2x2 ANOVA

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics, tidyr

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
dat <- structure(list(Age = c(20L, 20L, 20L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 25L, 
19L, 19L), Gender = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), 
    NoAS_Ver = c(2.125, 3.25, 1.875, 2.625, 3, 2.25, 3, 2.75, 
    3.625, 1.75), NoAS_VerDemo = c(3, 3, 2.125, 3.5, 2.625, 2.5, 
    3.125, 2.625, 3.25, 3.125), AS_Ver = c(2.875, 2.875, 2, 2.875, 
    2.38, 2.875, 2, 2.875, 2.375, 1.625), AS_VerDemo = c(2.125, 
    3.625, 3.375, 2.125, 3.25, 2.5, 2.5, 2.75, 4, 2.375)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

There is an age column, a gender column and 4 condition columns. I want to be able to perform a 2X2 repeated measures ANOVA but to do this, I need to split my condition columns so i can work with the levels.

I would like to split them into a "task level" (NoAs or AS) column, a "presentation level" (Ver or VerDemo) column and a "values" column whereby every row is an observation.

I feel like this can be done using the `tidyr` package however I'm unsure. So far I've tried:

```
split_dat <- dat %>%
  separate(NoAS_Ver, c(sep = "NoAS", "Ver")) %>%
  separate(AS_Ver, c(sep = "AS", "Ver")) %>%
  separate(NoAS_VerDemo, c(sep = "NoAS", "VerDemo")) %>%
  separate(AS_VerDemo, c(sep = "AS", "VerDemo"))
```

However this isn't what I'm looking for as I generate a lot of NA values. Does anybody have any tips on what else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

Think I've solved my problem:

```
split_data <- dat %>%
      gather("NoAS_Ver", "NoAS_VerDemo", "AS_Ver", "AS_VerDemo", key = "condition", value = "correctpairs") %>%
      separate(condition, into = c("task", "presentation"))
```

```
dat <- structure(list(Age = c(20L, 20L, 20L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 25L, 
19L, 19L), Gender = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), 
    CT = c("NoAS", "NoAS", "NoAS", "NoAS", "NoAS", "NoAS", "NoAS", 
    "NoAS", "NoAS", "NoAS"), Pres = c("Ver", "Ver", "Ver", "Ver", 
    "Ver", "Ver", "Ver", "Ver", "Ver", "Ver"), correctpairs = c(2.125, 
    3.25, 1.875, 2.625, 3, 2.25, 3, 2.75, 3.625, 1.75)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```